# What is the difference between SessionBundlePredict and SavedModelPredict in tensorflow serving?

Tags: tensorflow-serving

As I read in the source code, `SessionBundlePredict` uses `collection_def` in `MetaGraphDef` and `SavedModelPredict` uses `signature_def` in `MetaGraphDef` but I have no idea what is the difference between `collection_def` and `signature_def`.

My understanding of the two is that when I use `Exporter.export` then I should use `SessionBundlePredict` but when I use `SavedModelBuilder` then I should use `SavedModelPredict`?

Answer (score 0):

That's essentially correct. Specifically, the signature information for session bundles is stored in a special collection in collection_def.

However, SessionBundle and Exporter.export have been unsupported since [2017-06-30](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle/exporter.py#L44). So please use SavedModel going forward.